# How do I gain write permission for the defaults shell command?

Tags: terminal, permission, defaults

I recently migrated to a new Macbook.

If I do a `$ defaults write ...` in my shell, I get an error shaped like `defaults[12608:79345] Could not write domain Apple Global Domain; exiting`. Using `sudo` *does* work, however I have some defaults that are set in my .bashrc file -- these writes *did* work in my old system's .bashrc, without a sudo.

Q1: Are defaults saved across reboots? If so, I can removed these from my (cluttered) .bashrc and get on with life.

Q2: If defaults are not saved across reboots, what file(s) do I need to chown or chmod in order to get the `defaults write` to work quietly, in my .bashrc file?

What I've done so far:

- Read the `defaults` man page -- only seems to document the API.
- Skimmed around in [Apple's developer docs for Preferences](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/AccessingPreferenceValues/AccessingPreferenceValues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000059i-CH3-SW1). Again, this seems to be higher level API documentation for application developers who are using Cocoa.

Comment: You’re in the archive section, see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `defaults` command normally writes an entry into the relevant `.plist` file. The whole point of property list files is to retain settings between boots. You should not need to re-apply them after each boot.

Consequently, you should not need to run the defaults command in a `.bashrc` file, which runs at the start of every interactive shell session.

You should not need sudo for defaults commands such as these:

```
defaults write NSGlobalDomain AppleShowScrollBars -string "Always"
defaults write -g AppleEnableMenuBarTransparency -bool false
defaults write -app Safari AutoOpenSafeDownloads -bool false
defaults write com.apple.screencapture include-date -bool false
```

If you're trying to write some other type of `default` command to a system-level domain, then that might explain why you need `sudo`. Otherwise, the need for `sudo` is 'unexpected'.

Comment: Plist is really the last place to look for defaults since it now reads and writes to a consolidated database and only tangentially persists to a file for backwards compatibility. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults

Comment: I am running from an admin account, however I did have to do an account rename because my home directory got transferred over with the wrong name. That's probably the source of the 'unexpected'. Thank you for the clarification about preferences!

Comment: You said, "If you're running from an admin account, then that would be 'unexpected'." ... An Admin account still needs to use `sudo` when using `defaults write ...` to a file owned by `root`, which `/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist` is.

Comment: @user3439894 I can do defaults write -g without using sudo.

Comment: benwiggy, `ls -l /Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist` outputs `-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel ...` and since it is owned by `root` and there is no write permissions for **Group** and **Other** the latter which the **Admin** account falls under, you cannot, under default normal conditions write to `/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist` without the use of `sudo` from an **Admin** account!  `defaults write -g` without specifying the PLIST filename writes to `~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist` **not** `/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist`